# Why Symfony3 redirect slow

Tags: php, symfony

Recently I have tried to write a code in Symfony on page redirect (merely simple code for redirect without any other function), run it on localhost. However, the response returned is quite slow somehow (~500ms). What would be the possible cause of this as Laravel page redirect is faster than this.

Comment: In what mode you measure it? In development, production?

Comment: Open the Symfony's profiler and check what's the cause. By the way, in dev mode Symfony's much slower due to profiling/debugging work and not using cache in its full capabilities, so 500ms is not so bad in dev mode.

Comment: @KrzysztofRaciniewski I'm using development mode.

Comment: @JakubMatczak if I host my current Symfony project into a server eg: AWS, and put it under production mode, the respond will be faster ?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Symfony profiler (just click on the debug toolbar that gets displayed in the bottom of the pages if you are in a development environment) there is a "Last 10" requests button you can click to view profiler information for last couple of requests.

Find your request that returned the redirect response, click on the Token value and you will be able to see in the "Performance" page what is causing the slowdown.

Also, when in development mode some of the changes that you make will require the container to be rebuilt and this can take a while in the development environment with xdebug enabled.